# How do I make my website facebook likes correspond to my Facebook page likes?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am sure this question is answered all over the internet but I must have terrible research skills because I can't find it anywhere and I've been looking for hours.  I have a website, avidest.com, that has a facebook like button on the top.  I have a facebook page, also called avidest, located at https://www.facebook.com/pages/Avidest/491828310878179   How do I make it so that a like on the Facebook page is the same as a like on the main page and vice versa?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The like button on your website needs to refer to your facebook page. To do this just change

```
<fb:like href="http://www.avidest.com" send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

to

```
<fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Avidest/491828310878179" send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

and users who click the like button on your homepage will like your Facebook page.

Check out "Can I link the Like button to my Facebook page?" on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Do you know this for sure? AKA do you currently use this now? If this doesn't work, you can always use a Like Box https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: Should've linked to the docs in my answer, will edit it now. But yea, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/, check out Can I link the Like button to my Facebook page?

Comment: Thanks Alex.  If I change the href, will I lose the current likes that my website has?

Comment: Good find @AlexScarborough. You will not "lose" them, but any future likes will simply "like" the page

Comment: Thanks.  Also, when it shows up on someone's profile that they liked my page, if someone else click's on the link, will it take them to the fb page or the website.  Below is a meta property.  i don't know if it makes a difference.                                               <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.avidest.com" />

Comment: It will take them to the Facebook page.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there is any way to make it so that the likes for both the fb page and the website stay the same but that the link in newsfeeds is to the website like it is now?

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible :(